# Canonical bundle of curves of genus atleast $1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $g \geq 1$ and  $\mathcal O_X(1)$ be the very ample line bundle giving the embedding to some projective space. Then we know that $K_X$ is effective. Can we conclude that $h^0(K_X(m)) \neq 0$ for any $m \geq 1$?

Can we argue as follows: a section $s \in H^0(K_X)$ will induce a homomorphism $\mathcal O_X \to K_X$ as  $\mathcal O_X(U) \to K_X(U)$ by $a \to a.s|_U$. If it has a nontrivial kernel, then $s$ will be a torsion section of $K_X$, a contradiction as $K_X$ is locally free. Therefore we have an injective morphism $0 \to \mathcal O_X \to K_X$, which gives us $0 \to \mathcal O_X(m) \to K_X(m)$. Since $\mathcal O_X(1)$ is very ample (there it has sections) and locally free we have by same argument as before an injective morphism $\mathcal O_X \to \mathcal O_X(m)$ and hence an injective morphism $\mathcal O_X \to K_X(m)$. Now taking global sections we are done.

Suggestions, comments are corrections are welcome

Comment: I think your argument is correct.

Comment: @danneks, But it seems like the injectivity argument holds true for any locally free sheaf over any smooth projective variety (there is nothing specific about curves) as soon as it has a section. Also is this argument  true for a projective scheme?

Comment: @Sherlock Your concerns are more less addressed in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834806/global-section-defines-a-map-from-structure-sheaf In partciular (a) of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is also true for any torsion-free (coherent) sheaf $\mathcal F$ over an integral projective scheme $X$. If a non-zero map $s:\mathcal O_X\to \mathcal F$ has a non-trivial kernel, then there is a non-zero map $\mathcal O_Z\to\mathcal F$ for some closed subscheme $Z\subsetneq X$, so there is a section of $\mathcal F$ with support in $Z$. But locally we have $\mathcal F\cong\tilde{M}$ for some finitely generated module $M$, and the support of any $m\in M$ is equal to $V(\mathrm{Ann}(m))$, so the support of any non-zero section of $\mathcal F$ should be the whole $X$.